# Why won't trains come to my city?

Tags: simcity-2013

Why won't trains come to my city?

I have seen zero trains travelling on this path that starts in my city and goes past the Greats Works then off the Region Map.

No trains come to either my passenger train station or my trade port rail station. I understand if no passenger trains come since this city isn't connected directly to another city in the region, however I have been trying to export AND import goods yet no trains come to deliver any goods.

**Is this a bug? Is this particular region map & city location just doomed because it doesn't connect to another city?**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a trade port with a train attachment for it to ship the goods on?

Comment: I have a Trade Port and the Freight Rail Terminal (in the picture it's the building near my red line intersecting with the rail line) attached. I've used it before in a different city, I just was wondering if there was another reason for NO TRAINS other than it being bugged. I have tried re-starting the city/game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some researching I discovered this is indeed a bug. I discovered it on a compiled list of bugs on reddit:

[Compiled List of SimCity Bugs](http://www.reddit.com/r/SimCity/comments/1a0taq/compiled_list_of_suggestions_and_bug_reports_to/)

I was hoping it was some sort of gameplay mechanic I was missing, but sadly it's not.

Comment: Seeing all of those bugs, what is the benefit to buy this version when you have SimCity 4 ?